# How to create advance kibana visualisation

Tags: kibana, opensearch, kibana-4

Suppose i've following events in kibana dashboard.

```
Event 1 
{
   traceID : X
   eventName: Z
}

Event 2 
{
   traceID : X
   eventName: Y
}
```

Now , I want to to create a table visualization which returns following

- count = 0  // if same trace Id has both event published Z and Y.
- count = 1 // if only event Z is there.
- count = 0 // if only Y event is there.

How to do this in kibana dashboard visualization?

I'm trying to create a contextual dashboard in kibana by doing aggregation on multiple event with same tracking Id.